# Broadcasting a M*D matrix to N*D matrix in python (D is greater than 1, M>N)

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to subtract the rows of a MXD matrix from a NXD matrix (D is greater than 1, M > N) without using any for loops in Python. e.g. suppose I want to subtract the rows of a 100*25 matrix from the rows of a 20*25 matrix. How to write the code without for loops (I know I can do it using broadcasting but can't seem to code).

Comment: You can't - with broadcasting.  How do want you to reconcile the 100 rows of one with the 20 of the other?  Broadcasting doesn't deal with that kind of difference.

Comment: I guess you could tile it, but manually just looping 5 times is probably faster.

Comment: maybe I couldn't explain. I want to subtract each row of the 100X25 matrix from each row of the 20X25 matrix. e.g. Subtract row 1 of 100X25 matrix from rows 1 to 20 of 20X25 matrix, subtract row 2 of 100X25 matrix from rows 1 to 20 of 20X25 matrix, so on until row 100.

Comment: Your explanation is inconsistent

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I did it with two loops quite easily and also managed to do it within a single loop, but for a project, I can't use any for loops.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use for loops? Then go with the `np.tile` ~~(or is it `np.repeat`?)~~ method.

Comment: Can you show the loopy code?

Comment: So is the result supposed to be (100, 20, 25), for 100*20 pairings of rows?  Broadcasting handles that just fine.  `arr1[:,None,:]-arr2[None,:,:]`.  Or are you replicating the 2nd array 5 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

```
def subtract(A, B):
    m = A.shape[0]
    n = B.shape[0]
    C = np.empty_like(A)

    for i in range(m // n):
        C[i*n : (i+1)*n] = A[i*n : (i+1)*n] - B

    return C
```

Method 2:

```
def subtract(A, B):
    m = A.shape[0]
    n = B.shape[0]
    return A - np.tile(B, (m // n, 1))
```

Method 3:

```
def subtract(A, B):
    B_ = np.repeat(B, 5).reshape(B.size, -1).T.reshape(-1, B.shape[1])
    return A - B_
```

Comment: thanks. all these work. the loop code is similar to your method 1.